# What are the GCC default include directories?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, include-path

When I compile a very simple source file with gcc I don't have to specify the path to standard include files such as stdio or stdlib.

How does GCC know how to find these files?

Does it have the `/usr/include` path hardwired inside, or it will get the paths from other OS components?

Answer (score 293, accepted):

In order to figure out the default paths used by `gcc`/`g++`, as well as their priorities, you need to examine the output of the following commands:

1. For **C**:

```bash
echo | gcc -xc -E -v -
```

2. For **C++**:

```bash
echo | gcc -xc++ -E -v -
```

The credit goes to ***Qt Creator team***.

Here's a breakdown of the flags:

- `-x` selects the language, `C` or `C++` respectively
- `-E` makes gcc to run the preprocessor only, so no compilation takes place
- `-v` prints all the commands run, which is the key to dumping the standard paths
- `-` is the "input file" to preprocess, as a convention `-` stands for stdin (or stdout, depending on the context);

  `echo |` feeds an empty string to `gcc` so effectively we preprocess an empty file generated on the fly

Here's a nice explaining it in more detail: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=echo+%7C+gcc+-xc+-E+-v+-

Comment: `cpp -v /dev/null -o /dev/null`

Comment: @NehalJWani - good advice, but it doesn't work for Renesas's rx-elf-gcc cross-compiler. `rx-elf-cpp.exe: error: /dev/null: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Ihor - what does the - at the end of the command line do? I've seen questions about these dashes elesewhere on Stack Overflow, but their meaning varies by command. As far as I can tell when experimenting with Cygwin, it means gcc will do nothing and ignore all input except Ctrl-C. But gcc in an actual Bash shell might behave very differently.

Comment: `-` refers to `stdin` here. So you could also do:
`echo | gcc -xc++ -E -v -` and `echo | gcc -xc++ -E -v -`

Comment: How does this work? And why does it not work without the last dash? And why is there an `-E` when there's no file to compile?

Comment: @palapapa, I've updated the answer, hope it helps

Comment: @IhorKaharlichenko I noticed that you have added `echo |` but it worked without it. It even works without `-E`. Does that mean they are unnecessary?

Comment: @palapapa, I suppose it depends on the version of GCC. I tried omitting some of the flags from the above set, and even though there was some output each time, none of them contained the `include ... search starts here` piece which is the one we are looking for. Running on Ubuntu 22.04, GCC 11.3.0

Comment: It also works without pipes `gcc -xc -E -v /dev/null`

Comment: `gcc -E -Wp,-v -xc /dev/null 2>&1 | sed -n -e '/^ / s/^ //p'`

This gives you just the include list (no other preamble or info) and is usable in scripts. The actuals paths are printed to stderror and are prefixed with a space.

Answer (score 52):

There is a command with a shorter output, which allows to automatically cut the include pathes from lines, starting with a single space:

```
$ echo | gcc -Wp,-v -x c++ - -fsyntax-only
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/x86_64-redhat-linux
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../include/c++/4.8.2/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

The credit goes to the libc++ [front-page](http://libcxx.llvm.org/).

Comment: Use `/dev/null` instead of `-`, and you'll need no pipe

Comment: You only need to run the preprocessor, with `-E`, no need to run the compiler.

Answer (score 16):

To summarise the other answers:

For C++:

`c++ -xc++ /dev/null -E -Wp,-v 2>&1 | sed -n 's,^ ,,p'`

For C:

`cc  -xc   /dev/null -E -Wp,-v 2>&1 | sed -n 's,^ ,,p'`

Comment: I would suggest to make this a community wiki.

Answer (score 5):

Though I agree with Ihor Kaharlichenko’s answer for considering C++ and with abyss.7’s answer for the compactness of its output, they are still *incomplete* for the multi-arch versions of gcc because input processing depends on the command line parameters and macros.

Example:

`echo | /opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ -specs=nano.specs -mcpu=cortex-m4 -march=armv7e-m -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -x c++ -E -Wp,-v\
 - -fsyntax-only` yields

```
⋮
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../arm-none-eabi/include/newlib-nano                                                                                                              
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/9.2.1                                                                        
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/9.2.1/arm-none-eabi/thumb/v7e-m/nofp                                         
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/9.2.1/backward                                                               
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/include                                                                                                            
 /opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/include-fixed                                                                                                      
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include                                                                                  
⋮
```

whereas `echo | /opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ -x c++ -E -Wp,-v - -fsyntax-only` yields

```
⋮
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/9.2.1                                                                        
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/9.2.1/arm-none-eabi                                                          
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/9.2.1/backward                                                               
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/include                                                                                                            
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/include-fixed                                                                                                      
/opt/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2019-q4-major/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include                                                                                  
⋮
```

The former invocation utilizes `newlib` (see lines 1 and 3 of the output), the latter goes with the standard includes. The common files at the end of the list are an example for the usage of `include_next`.

Bottom line: Always consider all **macros** and **compiler options** when printing the include directories.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the following to list the default search paths:

```
$(gcc -print-prog-name=cc1) -v
```

Comment: This doesn't list the include paths. Only programs path and libraries path

Comment: `cc1` usually can't be called directly because it is an internal command which is not on the PATH. Maybe you want to edit your answer to describe where to find the file.

Comment: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `-v'

Comment: It only catches half of the include dirs that are found by `echo | gcc -Wp,-v -x c++ - -fsyntax-only`