# Need help setting up OpenCV on a Mac

Tags: macos, opencv

I'm a beginner programmer so may have missed something obvious here.
I'm following this tutorial to set up opencv on my Mac:
[OpenCV Linux Install](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html)
(Yes it's the linux version, but it's supposed to work with Mac)
I've followed all directions, and everything worked correctly. ( I did CMake, make, and sudo make install with no errors)

However, when I compile, I get errors saying the compiler cannot find the header files. Example:

```
fatal error: ' opencv2\opencv.hpp ' file not found
#include < opencv2\opencv.hpp >
```

I'm guessing I did not yet link my installation or maybe "set the path"? However, that was not in the directions.
Any ideas?

Comment: Let me understand: what fails compiling is your own project using some OpenCV functions, correct? What kind of project is yours? Basically what is happening is that the opencv libraries are not in your default include path (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980819/gcc-include-directories), so you have to specify it explicitly. Normally you will solve this by adding to the compiler line `-I<path to library include path>`, but the solution depends on the kind of project you have: if you have a CMake project you have a special command called `include_directories`

Comment: Thanks,
Yes, what fails is compiling my own project using OpenCV functions. It's actually a sample project I found from OpenCV website.
I tried compiling like so: g++ -I /Users/user/Desktop/opencv2/include main.cpp  and I got the same error I mentioned earlier. Inside my include directory there is cmake_install.cmake CMakeFiles and Makefile. How do I compile with "include_directories"?

Comment: Still same error. It's a capital i.
g++ -I/Users/user/Desktop/opencvbuild/include main.cpp 
main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp' file not found
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
         ^
1 error generated.

Comment: OK, I'm going to download source, make and make install again so I make sure I have everything right then check the path. Will post again in 30 mins.

Comment: I now compile like so, and get a linker error instead. I cut out a lot of the text because it was too long to post.
g++ -I/usr/local/include/ main.cpp 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::Mat::deallocate()", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::release() in main-937b25.o
  "cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)", referenced from:
  
....
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: How would that look like? Could you show the whole text that I should write in the terminal? (Like "g++ -l/usr/.....)

Comment: g++ -l/usr/local/include/ main.cpp  <-- that is a lowercase L. Get the same error though: main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp' file not found
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"

Comment: g++ -I-l-L/usr/local/include/opencv main.cpp   doesn't work either.

Comment: Thanks for your time so far. I don't know where the library file would be. My include folder is here. Maybe you could see? https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7NGOO5M53gKfkg4UjZfNUJlV2ZzZXhEbHEwZE53cm0wSnpkU3M0YUE5Q21lbjZJTmxaSFk&usp=sharing

Comment: I opened it. I don't know which of the files would be the library. Maybe you could have a look? https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7NGOO5M53gKbXlBdDhPRzRxR0U/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I just tried this, but got this error. :   g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -l<opencv_core> -L</usr/local/lib/> main.cpp
-bash: opencv_core: No such file or directory    Also tried this but got error g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -l<opencv_core.3.0.0> -L</usr/local/lib/> main.cpp
-bash: opencv_core.3.0.0: No such file or directory

Comment: I am learning a lot, thanks for your generosity. Now I'm back to the previous error: g++ -I/usr/local/include/opencv -lopencv_core -L/usr/local/lib/ main.cpp
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'opencv2\opencv.hpp' file not found
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

Comment: Still same error. g++ -I/usr/local/include -lopencv_core -L/usr/local/lib/ main.cpp
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'opencv2\opencv.hpp' file not found
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

Comment: Well when I did "make install" again earlier before I decided to check " install_manifest.txt file", there was a compilation error. I ignored it since I thought it would be OK since it compiled ok earlier. I'll do another make install now, hopefully no errors this time then do the g++ -I.... again

Comment: I got an error earlier because I didn't do "sudo make install" and did "make install" instead. I now compile like so, but still get a linker error: g++ -I/usr/local/include/ main.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::Mat::deallocate()", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::release() in main-93b4c7.o
  "cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)", referenced from:
      cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&) in main-93b4c7.o
... ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Same linker error: g++ -I/usr/local/include -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -L/usr/local/lib/ main.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)", referenced from:
      parseCmdArgs(int, char**) in main-200554.o
...ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Short linker error this time: g++ -I/usr/local/include -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lhighgui -L/usr/local/lib/ main.cpp
ld: library not found for -lhighgui
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: g++ -I/usr/local/include -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -L/usr/local/lib/ main.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)", referenced from:
      parseCmdArgs(int, char**) in main-884a9f.o
  "cv::imwrite(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> > const&)", referenced from:
 ...
      _main in main-884a9f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: For sure, never had a stranger spend so much effort helping me out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you ask the new question, show the compiler command line and the relevant part of the main.cpp code. Maybe link to this question, and take care of cleaning a bit the comments here above. Good luck! (Now gotta sleep :) )

Comment: Please also specify which OpenCV version you are dealing with (2.X or 3.X)

Comment: I stopped trying to get OpenCV to work on the terminal altogether, and very easily got it to work with Xcode after following these directions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJeP1juuHHY The link assumes that sudo make install was already done. Thanks again for all the help, I learned a bunch of things from that.

Comment: Glad I could help, it was my pleasure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error iterations, it looks your compiler line should be:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -L/usr/local/lib/ main.cpp main.cpp
```

Namely you should check your `install_manifest.txt` (resume of your opencv installation command, available in the opencv build directory) and add the options:

- `-I<path to the include directory>`
- `-l<name of the library file to be linked, removing "lib" prefix and any extension>` (repeat for as many libraries you need to link to)
- `-L<path to the library directory>`

For your system, the library files can be distinguished as having extension `.dylib` (and prefix `lib`). In Windows the extension would be `.dll` and for Unix `.so` (for dynamic libraries, while static libraries have extension `.lib` and `.a` respectively)