# Caffe fails to build on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: caffe, ubuntu-15.04

Having followed the [Caffe build instructions](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html#compilation), I get the following error

```
:~/App/caffe$ make all

PROTOC src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
CXX src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp
In file included from ./include/caffe/common_layers.hpp:10:0,
                 from ./include/caffe/vision_layers.hpp:10,
                 from src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp:6:
./include/caffe/data_layers.hpp:9:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include "hdf5.h"
                  ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:512: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/layer_factory.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/layer_factory.o] Error 1
```

I check the install of `hdf5: libhdf5-dev` with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
libhdf5-dev est déjà la plus récente version disponible
```

cuda7 is installed, opencv 3 ...

Comment: any chance translating these messages to English, please?

Comment: just  means that libhdf5-dev is installed ("the earliest version available")

Comment: do you mean the *latest* available version?

Comment: things start going better with:  `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/hdf5_hl.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/hdf5_hl.a` , `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/hdf5_hl.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/hdf5_hl.so` according to [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/cdyqjNpoFRY] but a problem with /usr/bin/ld persists

Comment: Try `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5_hl.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` - I think your symlinks are wrong.

Comment: @Shai : you're right!

Answer (score 3):

The steps required to make it build on Ubuntu 15.04 and Debian 8.x can be found in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2347).

To summarise:

```
#!/bin/bash
# manipulate header path, before building caffe on debian jessie
# usage:
# 1. cd root of caffe
# 2. bash <this_script>
# 3. build

# transformations :
#  #include "hdf5/serial/hdf5.h" -> #include "hdf5/serial/hdf5.h"
#  #include "hdf5_hl.h" -> #include "hdf5/serial/hdf5_hl.h"

find . -type f -exec sed -i -e 's^"hdf5.h"^"hdf5/serial/hdf5.h"^g' -e 's^"hdf5_hl.h"^"hdf5/serial/hdf5_hl.h"^g' '{}' \;
```

Followed by

Modify `INCLUDE_DIRS` in `Makefile.config`

```
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial/
```

And finally, make some simlinks to HD5

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libhdf5_serial.so.8.0.2 libhdf5.so
sudo ln -s libhdf5_serial_hl.so.8.0.2 libhdf5_hl.so
```

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 15.10.  I have to add `LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial` to **Makefile.config**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try installing the entire [hdf5](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hdf5) package, not only the dev portion.

If that doesn't work, verify that you have the hdf5.h header on your system and check its path.

You can check gcc's include path with the command [[source]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6666338/2929337)

```
gcc -xc -E -v -
```

Comment: A bunch of hdf5 files are installed: hdf5-tools, libhdf5-8, libhdf5-cpp-8, libhdf5-dev,hdf5-helpers, libhdf5-serial-dev

Comment: $ whereis hdf5.h
hdf5: /usr/include/hdf5

Comment: is `'/usr/include/hdf5'` on your `'INCLUDE_PATH'`?

Comment: Modifying data_layers.hpp didn't help: $ make all
PROTOC src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
CXX src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp
In file included from ./include/caffe/common_layers.hpp:10:0,
                 from ./include/caffe/vision_layers.hpp:10,
                 from src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp:6:
./include/caffe/data_layers.hpp:9:39: fatal error: /usr/include/hdf5: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
 #include "/usr/include/hdf5"//"hdf5.h"

Comment: modifying data_layers.hpp as #include "/usr/include/hdf5"
instead of #include "hdf5.h" failed too (same error)

Comment: installing hdf5 from source may be the solution

Comment: echo $INCLUDE_PATH is empty

Comment: #include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.