# List and view gcc C11 header files

Tags: c, gnu, c11, codelite

How can I view C11 header files content of gcc compiler in CodeLite on Linux? if not possible, How/Where can I view them?

Please ignore this location en.cppreference.com/w/c/header since it's just documentary with no actual header file content

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6666338/1505939) for how to find the directory containing header files, with gcc.  For other compilers you may have to google or consult their documentation,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the system header files, including the standard C header files, are under `/usr/include`. You can open any of them with any editor, including the CodeLite editor.

Comment: well - that's for default installs. It's possible that a system might have come with C89 headers in `/usr/include`, and then someone installs a later version of gcc to a different location such as `/usr/local/include`.