# C++ how to create a 'global' library

Tags: c++

I'm working on a project that has the line: `#include <fftw3.h>`

Now I can simply download and make [fftw](http://fftw.org). But how do I make it a 'global' library?

I have tried adding it to `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` but this doesn't seem to work. I'm constantly ending up with this error: `main.c:30:10: fatal error: 'fftw3.h' file not found`

So my question is: where do I need to make the fftw library (or any library for that matter) to make it globally accessible?

*note: I might use the term global incorrectly, in that case, please let me know what the correct term would be.*

**Update:** The command is:

```
gcc -Wall -march=native -O3 -ffast-math `pkg-config --cflags fftw3` `pkg-config --cflags sndfile` -c -o main.o main.c
```

`main.c` contains the line

```
#include <fftw3.h>
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? You normally have a setting for the paths that it examines to find the files. Or try adding it to your Path environment variable.

Comment: search for a package to install at the *system* level for  your os, if you were on some linux distro, look for an appropriate package from the repo and then install that. That will drop in the headers and pre-built libraries in the right places..

Comment: use `-I` compile switch ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the GCC default include directories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980819/what-are-the-gcc-default-include-directories)

Comment: @TamásSzelei thanks for this link. But now I would like to learn how I can add the fftw lib to one of these directories...

Comment: It may be a duplicate @TamásSzelei , but not a duplicate of that exact question

Comment: @BobvanLuijt copy it there? Not sure what you are after. There is no magic involved. The build system of the project in question might provide an install function which copies to these directories.

Comment: @DarioOO I don't know what you mean by that. Is it a duplicate in your opinion or not? I fail to see any possible middle ground. Don't get me wrong, it's fine if you disagree with it being a duplicate.

Comment: I was simply saying that I don't believe your question is technically a duplicate, however it suprise me no one already asked the same as OP (maybe there exist a duplicate wich I was not able to find).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

beign able to include files using `<file>` is generally bad practise, it increase the risk of files with same name became ambiguos (especially on big projects).

You can achieve that by specifing additional global include directories using the `-I` compiler option. However there is no best way to achieve that (it depends on how project is organized and how it is big).

**Include by absolute path:**

```
#include <file>
#include <somepath/file2>
```

**Pros:**

- Source code structure is more flexibile (you can move your files without warrying about breaking compilation)

**Cons:**

- More chance of name clash between files

**Include by path relative to source file:**

```
#include "../file"
#include "../somepath2/file2"
```

**Pros:**

- No chance for name clash, there exist only 1 file given any relative path

**Cons:**

- You cannot move files around otherwise relative paths needs to be changed (however refactoring tools of your IDE may help with that)

Definitely I prefer using absolute path for standard library stuff and eventually **FEW** other dependencies, while otherwise I use only relative paths. You should note that when the compiler search for global include files, it will search in all provided `-I` directories, so if you abuse that feature it is likely you will increase compile time.

Of course even when using global includes, I prefer adding just 1 extra directory and organize that so that the compiler doesn't have to guess paths

```
Include
  +FolderNameSpace1
  +FolderNameSpace2
```

So I have just to add the namespace when including

```
#include <FolderNameSpace1/File1>
```

Some open source projects, had this problem in mind, however since not all people is willing to spend too much time organizing folder structure, their developers used the more simple strategy to prepend a suffix on Header file names (to avoid name clash).. In example in Ogre you have to do:

```
#include <OgreFileName>
//or (depending on how your project is organized)
#include "../Deps/OgreFileName"
```

---

**So after some premise, to answer your question**,

you have to add as "global include directory" the directory that has all include files you want to use, so Given you are using GCC and your project is organized like that:

```
Project
  +FFWT
    +includes
  +yourfolder
    +yoour files
```

you have just to do:

```
gcc -Wall -march=native -O3 -ffast-math -I../FFWT/includes c -o main.o main.c
```

***(I am assuming you are calling GCC from inside "yourfolder")***

How to add additional global include directories:

- [GCC/Clang GUIDE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Directory-Options.html)
- [MSVC GUIDE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a precise answer the way you put it - there is no "global" library, because "fftw3.h"is a header file.

There are 3 things here:
**1) Where you find header files**
**2) Where you find static (or stub/import) libraries**
**3) Where you find dynamic libraries (at runtime)**

For 1), the answer is "depends on the configuration of your build tool".
So is 2). For 3, it is usually "in the path, in the same folder as the executable, in the current directory, or in a platform specific directory". It would be slightly different for Windows, Linux, or another platform.

In short, you will need to configure your build tool for it.

EDIT:
Now that we know what your tool is, I would suggest reading this short page explaining how GCC looks for headers (your .h file). You can either put your header file in one of the search paths (sloppy!, not recommended), or put your "extra" headers in a directory of your choosing and add it to the compilation command with the "-I" parameter.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

Comment: Thanks, this is bringing me a bit closer. I have added the initial g++ command to my question. Do you mean I somehow need to set the path for ` --cflags fftw3`?

Comment: Yes you need both to specify a path to header files, and a path to the static library, see my answer :)