# How to import libraries to a text editor

Tags: c++, ubuntu, sdl, libraries, atom-editor

How do I import libraries that I can include with #include <> in C++. Specifically, I am trying to import the SDL library, I am using Atom, and my operating system is ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You simply should install these libraries on your system, and adapt the makefiles. The text-editor doesn't have to do anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is default path where compiler searches libraries.

[What are the GCC default include directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980819/what-are-the-gcc-default-include-directories)

If you are using gcc/g++:

```
gcc -xc++ -E -v -
```

Or you have to specify path to the library:

```
#include "../folder1/header1.h"
#include "../folder2/header2.h"
```

As already mentioned, you should have this library on your local system.