# How does GCC implement the C++ standard allocator?

Tags: c++, gcc, memory-management, allocator

I am not familiar with tracking down the source codes to figure out the GCC STL implementation (libstdc++) of the C++ standard allocator, and I cannot find any brief explanation, documentation and technical reports that describe what the memory model that GCC selects.

I guess that GCC uses several fixed-size buckets for storing small objects of the same  size in bytes and allocate large memory space *ad hoc* for large objects over the specific size.

What is the specific memory model that GCC selects for the C++ standard allocator?

Comment: Why don't you look into the header?

Comment: @manni66 Compiler headers often call intrinsic functions instead of actually containing code.

Comment: Are you asking about `std::allocator` specifically or the heap? One is likely implemented on top of the other.

Comment: @Useless Yes. I am wondering how `std::allocator` is implemented. Especially, the exact number of thresholds, the bucket data structures, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cannot find any brief explanation, documentation and technical reports that describe what the memory model that GCC selects

Read the code. It's open source, and it's included with the compiler as plain text.

If you're not sure *where* your standard headers are, you can do one of two things:

1. learn how to ask the compiler [as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4980819/212858)
2. trick the compiler into telling you, eg. by trying to do something `std::allocator` cannot

   ```
   #include <memory>

   int main() {
       std::allocator<int> a;
       a.allocate(&a);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

   gives

   ```
   error ... 
   In file included from \
     /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
   ```

When you find out that `std::allocator` just uses the heap to make all those decisions, you can look at the [glibc source](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git) for `malloc`.

Comment: Thanks for that. I found that the actual implementation is in `new_allocator.h`, and it is simply an wrapper of `new` and `delete`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`std::allocator` just uses `operator new` and `operator delete`, and those in turn simply wrap `malloc` and `free`.

Thus the implementation is delegated to the C library, whichever happens to be in use.