# Problems installing packages which use SDL2 via cgo on Windows 7

Tags: go, installation, windows-7-x64, cgo

I have problems installing SDL2 for golang, using Visual Studio Code.

I try to get the package:

```
"C:\Users\Bob\go\src\flappyGopher>go get -v github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/sdl
github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/sdl
# github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/sdl
In file included from ..\github.com\veandco\go-sdl2\sdl\audio.go:4:0:
./sdl_wrapper.h:2:23: fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated."
```

I used this manual: https://github.com/vinzBad/go-sdl2-tut/blob/master/00_preparation/windows.md

I have also the env variables:

```
CGO_CFLAGS C:\MinGW64\mingw64\include
GOPATH C:\Users\Bob\go
GOROOT C:\Go\
PATH ... C:\MinGW64\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin;C:\MinGW64\mingw64\bin;C:\Users\Bob\Downloads\SDL2-2.0.8\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2
```

edit:the gcc output looks like a mess

```
C:\Users\Bob>gcc -xc -E -v -
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-5.1.0/configure --build=x86_64-w64-  mingw32 --e
nable-targets=all --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable
-libgomp --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-cxx-flags=-DWINPTHREAD_STATIC -
-disable-build-with-cxx --disable-build-poststage1-with-cxx --enable-libstdcxx-d
ebug --enable-threads=posix --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-full
y-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-threads --enable-libstdcxx-time --with-gnu-l
d --disable-werror --disable-nls --disable-win32-registry --prefix=/mingw64tdm -
-with-local-prefix=/mingw64tdm --with-pkgversion=tdm64-1 --with-bugurl=http://td
m-gcc.tdragon.net/bugs
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm64-1)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 C:/Program Files/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/cc1.exe
 -E -quiet -v -iprefix C:/Program Files/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-min
gw32/5.1.0/ -D_REENTRANT - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/Program Files/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/
x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/Program Files/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/
x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/Program Files/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/
x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "C:/Program Files/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/
x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 C:/Program Files/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include
 C:/Program Files/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../..
/include
 C:/Program Files/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include-fixed
  C:/Program Files/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../..
/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
End of search list.
```

Comment: From windows command prompt, you need to set `CGO_FLAGS=-IC:\Users\Bob\Downloads\SDL2-2.0.8\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\`, then execute *go get ...*

Comment: I've tried it, but still the same errormessage
C:\Users\Bob>set CGO_FLAGS=-IC:\Users\Bob\Downloads\SDL2-2.0.8\x86_64-w64-mingw3
2\include

C:\Users\Bob>go get -v github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/sdl
github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/sdl
# github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/sdl
In file included from go\src\github.com\veandco\go-sdl2\sdl\audio.go:4:0:
./sdl_wrapper.h:2:23: fatal error: SDL2/SDL.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](https://www.google.com/search?q="fatal+error"+"No+such+file+or+directory+compilation+terminated.").

The reason is `go install` tried to compile some
[`cgo`](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)
code of the `github.com\veandco\go-sdl2` package, and that code apparently
wants to use the [C header files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive#C/C++)
of the `libsdl2` library¹.

You need to make [`libsdl2`](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php)
available to the compiler.

To figure out where the C compiler expects to find the include (header)
files, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6666338/720999).

---

¹ That's how C works. To use a compiled library in other C code, the compiler
usually needs to know the definitions of the types and functions provided
by that library. The formats of such libraries—contrary to Go libraries—do not typically embed type information in their metadata, so the compiler
needs to get that information from somewhere. In C and C++ world this information is commonly kept in the so-called include (also: header) files
which are included—through the use of a so-called preprocessor—both into the
code used to build a library and the code which uses the library.

Comment: do I have to know how C works to use Go?
I'll update the gcc output in the first posting