# How to override -nostdinc for GCC

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, stm32, zephyr-rtos

I try to cross-compile for STM32 arm-none-eabi using zephyrproject.org. Zephyr adds `-nostdinc` flag to every C/C++ file. I cannot find how to override this without fixing build system sources.

#### Need option like `-stdinc` (unrecognized). Is there any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [find out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6666338/5131711) what the default include directories are, and add them back with the [`-I`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) option.

Answer (score 1):

This info is from the man page of gcc

**Options for Directory Search**
       These options specify directories to search for header files, for libraries and for parts of the compiler:

```
   -I dir
   -iquote dir
   -isystem dir
   -idirafter dir
```

Answer (score 1):

@kyb I ran into the same problem and eventually found the proper solution for Zephyr:

simply add `CONFIG_NEWLIB_LIBC=y` to your `prj.conf` file !