# Is there a python sys.path equivalent in c++

Tags: python, c++

In python if we run

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

it will give us a list of directories where python interpreter or compiler searches in when an `import` keyword encountered.

similarly is there a command(or a CLI command) or function in `c++` which do the same as python's `sys.path`

More information, I am using windows, mingw gcc version 6.3.0

Comment: C++ doesn't have anything like `import`, so what would an equivalent function be?

Comment: @Chipster He's not asking about listing a directory, he's asking about a search path used for importing modules.

Comment: @Barmar `import` is roughly equivalent to `include` but slightly more flexible.

Comment: but c++ have #include equivalent as import

Comment: `#include` happens at compile time, not while the program is running.

Comment: @Barmar as in the working directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the GCC default include directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980819/what-are-the-gcc-default-include-directories)

Comment: The closest I can think of are the set of directories you can update with `-I` and `-L` when compiling and linking.

Comment: What are you intending to do with this information in C++? By the time the program is running, it's too late to do anything with the directories used for `#include` and linking.

Comment: @barmar I just want to understand how it works. In future if I create my own files what are options I have to place my files .

Comment: Understand how what works? Python is interpreted, C++ is compiled. Python loads modules while the script is running, with C++ you link everything when you're compiling.

Comment: As far as I know, C++ doesn't provide any introspection for this information.

Comment: @RyanHaining Thanks for suggestion, it solved my question I guess, I can see some folder in the command line. I guess those are the folders compiler searching

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your answer. I meant how C++ works.

Comment: Since it is duplicated Do I have to delete the question now

Comment: @Chipster your suggestions also helped me. thanks.

Comment: you don't have to delete the question, it will be marked as a duplicate following other close voters.