# C++ compiler can't find cairo.h on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, cairo

I've installed Cairo and Pkgconfig using `brew` on my mac, but unfortunately when I do `#include <cairo.h>`, my program can't compile because it can't find `cairo.h`.

Has anyone experienced something like this before?

Comment: Check if `cairo.h` is in include paths https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980819/what-are-the-gcc-default-include-directories

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with cario, but I'll ask: are you sire your compiler is configured to look in the right place for the include files?