# Build Can't Find Stdio.h But I Can...?

Tags: c, ubuntu, include

I have `#include <stdio.h>` (no extra spaces) and `locate stdio.h` shows a few viable options. And yet, when I build, it always says it can't be found. I can include it with a full path `#include "/usr/include/stdio.h"`, but then its own dependencies (features.h) can't be found. I tried specifically sourcing the /usr/include folder which I imagine should already be good to go anyway, but that doesn't help it find it either. So... what the heck? I'm also building with sudo privileges. I can't fathom a good reason for it to not be found.

output from `make V=1 VERBOSE=1`

```
******************** Release Build **********************
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-58-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/username/project modules 
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-58-generic'
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;                          \
/bin/false)
mkdir -p /home/username/project/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /home/username/project/.tmp_versions/*                                        */
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/home/username/project
******************** Release Build **********************
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/home/username/project/.file_main.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include  -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fshort-wchar -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -fno-PIE -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CRC32=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX512=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mindirect-branch=thunk-extern -mindirect-branch-register -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fno-merge-all-constants -fmerge-constants -fno-stack-check -fconserve-stack -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=strict-prototypes -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -Werror=designated-init -DCHARACTER_DRIVER -DCUSTOM_LOGIC -DOEM_001_CUSTOM_LOGIC -DNO_STATS_DEBUG  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"file_main"'  -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"file"' -c -o /home/username/project/file_main.o /home/username/project/file_main.c
In file included from /home/username/project/file_main.c:13:0:
/home/username/project/file.h:10:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: If the compiler can't find `<stdio.h>`, it's probably misconfigured/misinstalled.

Comment: Where is the executable of your compiler? The shown paths don't look like "close neighbours" of likely compiler locations.

Comment: Are you compiling with `-nostdinc`?

Comment: Compiler is located at /usr/bin. I don't see "nostdinc" in the makefile anywhere. How would one "configure" gcc to know to include the /usr/include folder if not via sourcing? My colcon builds work fine to find stdio.h. I presume that still uses gcc, no?

Comment: What's the command-line invocation?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980819/what-are-the-gcc-default-include-directories) to find out which paths are searched.

Comment: Thanks, @thebusybee. The /usr/include folder appears to be listed when using those commands.

Comment: @JL2210 To be honest, I'm not familiar enough with make-files to even know where the command is that's starting the build and I can't share the file's contents for proprietary reasons. If I were to guess, however, it would be the part of the make file that says default: $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) SUBDIRS=$(CURDIR) modules. Maybe the problem is SUBDIRS overriding any other potential include locations?

Comment: If you run `make -n` it would just print the commands without executing them. You can copy and edit these to show them here. But even with the standard call to `make` the commands are printed by default. Presumably we need only the command before the erroneous compile.

Comment: @thebusybee, it appears to be just as I showed above. It turns into "make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-58-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/username/project modules"

Comment: It looks like the makefile is printing an abbreviated version of the compilation command.  Try passing `V=1` to `make` and it will probably print the full command.

Comment: @dbush, it looks like after a V=1, I can now see the -nostdinc flag. I'm not sure where it's coming from though. Any idea where it might be that I could remove it?

Comment: You're building a kernel module.

Comment: @JL2210, yes. I am attempting to update a driver from a supplier that was made for 14.04 and has a few deprecated/different functions in 16.04. When I run it after updating, it crashes, so I'm trying to add debugging print statements to see where it's crashing. Something inherent with kernels that prevent std includes?

Comment: @JL2210, feel free to answer that the issue to my specific question is the -nostdinc flag and I will mark it correct. It seems I now simply have more questions on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `printk`, not `printf`. Its definition is in `linux/printk.h`, not `stdio.h`.

Please include these details in your question the next time you ask.

The reason your build is not able to find `stdio.h` is because it's not available in the kernel sources, and you're compiling with `-nostdinc`. `-nostdinc` causes all the default search paths to be ignored.

Comment: My question was why stdio could not be found, not how to debug or print statements for a kernel (which will be a followup question as printk does not suit my needs). Now knowing that it could not be found "because kernels can't use stdio and somehow includes the -nostdinc flag during build" (though I'm not sure why or how), I can now move on to other questions. If  you update your answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @CodeMonkey See edit. I'm still going to keep the original (for future reference), but I added a note about `stdio.h`.

Comment: Fair enough. Had I known that kernel drivers were handled differently, I might have known to include that info, but then I probably would have already known my answer :-p