# for c/cpp include path by adding the path to system file and run

Tags: c++, c, gcc, path, export

A file called test.cpp in ~/test
 code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "add.h" 
int main(){
    printf("%d\n",add(1,2));
}
```

file add.h is in ~/test/1, which is just a subdirctory

code is

```
int add(int a, int b){return a+b;}
```

then i use export

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/test/1
```

[image]

Is there any way to fix that?

not using #include "1/test"

any help is much appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980819/what-are-the-gcc-default-include-directories

Comment: it should be `#include "1/add.h"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`export` is used to create an environment variable for the shell. It has no bearing on where the compiler looks to find your include files.

`gcc -Itest/1 test.cpp` should make it work. The -I argument gives gcc a path to look for include files in.

You can use a *makefile* or *cmake* to give these specific instructions to gcc if you like.