# The ever-popular vscode #include iostream error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I've uninstalled and reinstalled mingw-64 and vscode, following the instructions at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw.  I've set the include path and the compiler path.  I look in the directory where all the header files are located, and, sure enough, iostream is in there.

This time I didn't get the squiggle line under #incluide  the way I had before, when I typed in the helloworld program.  Great! I thought, it's fixed.  I compiled the program.  The result?

```
helloworld.cpp:1:10: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Here's the path: C:\MinGW_w64\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\8.1.0\include\c++
Here's the compiler path: C:/MinGW_w64/mingw32/bin/g++.exe"

And, what the heck, here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<string> msg {"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code!"};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you might want to consider switching to Linux, for C++ development, where every Linux distribution comes with the latest version of gcc, fully configured, and ready to use? It takes me about an hour to install Linux on a new system, which is probably less time than it would take to figure out why MS-Windows is borked.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik To be honest, you can easily get the latest GCC on Windows too, if you know where to look (MSYS2). :)

Comment: @lbrw This doesn't have anything to do with VScode, right? Can you compile the code directly from the terminal?

Comment: You've installed mingw64, so why is your include path under mingw32?

Comment: Consider also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980819/what-are-the-gcc-default-include-directories